# JAX-WS & Glassfish: where is my WSDL?

Tags: glassfish, jax-ws

I have a JAX-WS that so far ran on TomCat and JBoss. So far everything worked perfectly.

Because of various reasons I switched to Glassfish 4. I slightly adapted my war and deployed it to Glassfish. Everything seems to work regarding deployment, the web service appears under "Applications" and is enabled.

However, I am not able to find the link to the WSDL or the endpoint. Furthermore, somehow, I get the impression the web service was not really deployed as web service (I compare to some screenshots I found). This is what it displays under "edit application":

[image: modules and components]

What could have gone wrong? Is something wrong with my web.xml or should I check my annotations again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the outdated web.xml. I created a new web.xml (now named glassfish-web.xml) with the following content

```
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD 
GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" 
"http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
  <context-root>myApp</context-root>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

and now it works.

Comment: If this solves your problem, feel free to mark it as answer, so that the question is recorded as answered. There is nothing wrong in answering your own questions.

Comment: Good point! :-) I had to wait anyway two days until I could do so :-) but thanks for pointing me to it!